# Why would my touchstart and touchend events not fire on Safari mobile?

Tags: javascript, ios, touch

[Here](http://phobogniyi.localtunnel.me/) is my app, running locally. My `touchstart` and `touchend` events fire correctly in the desktop Chrome mobile simulator, as well as on a friend's Android, but in Safari they do nothing. I have the viewport meta tag. It seems as though Safari is not registering as a mobile browser/device and, therefore, not registering touches.

[Here](http://codepen.io/colshacol/pen/vKaZmV.babel) is the file that I am working with the touch events. (It wouldn't format correctly here.)

(Swipe right to mark for deletion, swipe right again to confirm. Swipe left to mark complete.)